# A question about the meaning of the notation $(\frac{\partial}{\partial \cosh r})^2 f(r).$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

I am studying a calculus book and in an exercise I found the expression

$$(\frac{\partial}{\partial \cosh r})^2 f(r),$$
where $f(r)$ is a polynomial function of $\sinh r$.

Any help about the meaning of the notation that uses the author?
About the exponent, I am sure that he means $(\frac{\partial}{\partial \cosh r})^2 f(r)= (\frac{\partial}{\partial \cosh r})[(\frac{\partial}{\partial \cosh r}) f(r)]$. The Question is about $(\frac{\partial}{\partial \cosh r})$

Comment: You should write out what $F$ is?

Comment: It means differentiating wrt a $\mathrm{coshr}$ "variable" inside an expression. However if that's the way it is presented it's very unintuitive. Would you mind posting the original quotation so that we can see the context?

Comment: This is probably an abuse of notation with the inverse function theorem/chain rule. I am guessing this means $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\cosh'(r)}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ or something similar.

Comment: @CameronWilliams if that's true that's serious abuse alright

Comment: Ah the answer has it right. I forgot to apply the inverse.

Answer (score 2):

let $$a = \cosh(r)$$ and $$\hat{F}\ \ \ \text{s.t.}\ \ \ \hat{F}(\cosh(r),x) = F(r,x)$$
then
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \cosh(r)}F(r,x) = \frac{d}{da} \hat{F}(a,x)$$

similarly with the chain rule:

$$ \rightarrow\frac{d}{da}F(\operatorname{arccosh}(a),x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}\frac{d}{dr}F(r,x)$$